# Visual Basic - Password Validation

Tags: vb.net

I have recently started learning Visual Basic.

I wanted to make a username & password validation...
I named my password textbox as `textPassword`, my username textbox as `textUser`, the displaying label as `display`, and a button for submission as `submitBtn`.

And here is the code (of the submit button)
:

```
if textUser = "Arya" then 
    display.Text = "Username Is Correct!"
end if

if textPassword = "12345" then 
    display.Text = "Password Is Correct!" 
end if
```

This is the error I'm getting:

> Value of type 'TextBox' cannot be converted to 'String'

Please tell me my mistake so I can change it...
THANK YOU!!!

Comment: Ok...
The error was : - Value of type 'TextBox' cannot be converted to 'String'
Pls help...

Comment: txtUser is a textbox, and it HAS a value. To ask if a textbox IS it's value will return false. You need to compare the value to what you expect, e.g., `if textUser.Value == "Arya" then`

Comment: Use `If textUser.Text = ...`. Also, based on the error message, it looks like you're using VB.NET (which is different from both VBA and VB6).

Comment: @Red What TextBox are you referring to that has a `.Value` property?

Comment: The question was originally tagged as VB6/VBA, which use .Value. Should have been .Text though as they are actually asking about VB.Net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As other comments have said, textUser and textPassword are fields and so you need to get the inside value by using `textUser.Text` or `textUser.Value`.
By doing "If textUser", you are checking if text user exists and so it will return true.

Comment: What TextBox are you referring to that has `.Value` property?